# How can I make an undecorated window in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I like to create a Cocoa window without any chrome whatsoever. The only thing the user should see is what I draw.

I've discovered I can create a custom NSView but does this have to be in an NSWindow to display? If not, how can I display it without putting it in an NSWindow? If it does have to be in an NSWindow, how do I stop the window from drawing a title bar and other chrome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the sample:

http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/index.html

Answer (score 1):

> I've discovered I can create a custom NSView but does this have to be in an NSWindow to display?

Yes.

> If it does have to be in an NSWindow, how do I stop the window from drawing a title bar and other chrome?

Use [NSBorderlessWindowMask](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSBorderlessWindowMask) when you create your window. (Assuming you aren't using a custom subclass of NSWindow, this means not creating the window instance in a nib. If you want to lay out your view hierarchy in a nib, do that in a top-level custom view, then load the nib and set that view as the window's content view.)

Comment: You can still create the window in a nib - just pass the borderless flag to super in the window's initializer and set the window to your subclass in the nib.

Comment: That's assuming you subclass NSWindow for it.